# PHP - clone an object that contains references to itself?

Tags: php, oop, drupal, cloning, self-reference

What is the best way to create a clone of a complex PHP object that includes many references to itself, so that the new object's references point to its own methods and properties, not those of the original object?

I understand [from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) that `$new_object = clone $old_object;` creates a shallow copy that keeps references where they are. So presumably $new_object's references will point to methods on the old object?

A comment on that manual page suggests that `$new_object = unserialize(serialize($old_object));` is a way to create a deep copy. Sounds promising, I'm not sure exactly what this approach would mean for my case: whether references are converted to point to the clone, or made absolute, or something else, and if does do what I want, whether it's the best way.

I'd like to know if there's an established, standard way to do this.

*(Note: the object in question is a Drupal Views object, but this question is about PHP objects in general: the only important features of this object are, that it is huge, and contains many references to itself that recurse if you try to navigate the whole tree.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple test will reveal what happens:

```
$old = new stdClass();
$old->foo = 'bar';
$old->baz = &$old;

print_r($old);

$new = unserialize(serialize($old));

$new->foo = 'new';

print_r($new);
print_r($new->baz->foo);
```

This code shows that the self-ref now points to the clone. http://codepad.org/dSnZ5I10

Comment: Cool, thanks, +1. Any idea about whether this is a good generalisable and standard approach - e.g. if there are any performance drawbacks when the object is huge? Seems to perform okay in my testing but my testing is very basic.

Comment: It will get slower the bigger your object is, but so will anything. I guess it depends on how big your object is to begin with - it the serialized version takes up more than half of your memory (it's a just a sting, so `strlen()` will tell you how big it is) then this approach is bad, but otherwise the execution time should be trivial.

Comment: Awesome. So memory use simply == strlen(serialize($object)) - that makes sense and answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's some basic testing and results. Not a complete answer but hopefully useful. Also please correct me if my approach is wrong. Assume $view is an object that already contains lots of self-reference and loads of data:

```
      $view->somedata = "This is the default";
      $view->selfreference =& $view->somedata;

      $new = clone $view;
      $new2 = unserialize(serialize($view));

      $view->somedata = "This is view";
      $new->somedata = "This is new";
      $new2->somedata = "This is new2";

      echo("$view: ".$view->selfreference);
      echo("$new: ".$new->selfreference);
      echo("$new2: ".$new2->selfreference);
```

Results:

```
'$view: This is new'
'$new: This is new'
'$new2: This is new2'
```

So at first investigation, it looks like the shallow clone with `clone` points the self-references to the original, and the `unserialize(serialize())` approach maintains the reference and points it to the new object.

So it looks like `unserialize(serialize())` works and doesn't crash out with an infinite loop or excessive recursion. I'd like to hear people's thoughts on whether this is a best, standard and/or accepted approach.